# Catalina is in Turkish but some apps are in Russian

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MBA and the language is in Turkish. However, some apps are in Russian. The only Russian-related thing on my system is a keyboard layout. Aside from that, `env` in terminal shows nothing Russian related. The latest app I came across having Russian in Aegisub. How can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: IIRC, If the developer of the app does not provide localization for different languages, the app will use the language it was coded in. Your MBA may be running in the Turkish macOS, but the app can't provide the Türk characters.

Comment: Can I get apps to fallback to English if that’s the case?

Comment: To get fallback to English, make sure English is second on the list of your preferred languages, right after Turkish.

Comment: It all depends on if the app developer has an English localization for the app. I don't know if there's a requirement to have an English localization. Somebody with more app development chops needs to chime in.

Comment: @TomGewecke you mean System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources, right?

Comment: I think @TomGewecke means that you should make English the second language in **Preferred Languages** in **System Preferences > Language & Region**.

Answer (score 1):

If your app includes an English localization, you can get this to display by going to System Preferences > Language and Region and making sure that English is the second item on the list of Preferred Languages, right after Turkish.  Input Sources preferences are irrelevant for your problem.